# See the files behind AWS athena with a query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Can you ask AWS Athena for the S3 files that are behind a table?

For example

```
msck show partitions
```

would give

```
s3://some-bucket/some-key/some-table/file1.csv,
s3://some-bucket/some-key/some-table/file2.csv
```

and similarly for tables which are partitioned or bucketed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Athena/Presto has a hidden column called `$path` which can be used to figure out which file a row comes from. You can use it to also figure out all files in a partition or table:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "$path"
FROM my_table
```

Please note that in Athena engine v1 this was a *very* expensive operation, but in engine v2 it's optimized and at least the query above won't scan any data.

See the [docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html#extra-hidden-columns) for some more information.

Comment: This doesn't work for views by the way.

Comment: Nvm, added the docs. Google is easier when you know the keyword.